# MySQL: Subquery returns more than 1 row with sum statement

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a list consisting of two columns: USERS and DIFFERENCE_ACTIVITY1_5_DAYS

I'm trying to do this from a table that gathers information from users on three different activities (activity1, activity2, activity3) on each day. Which results in a table that looks like this:

| Username | Activity | Value | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| User1 | Act1 | 3 | 2022-07-01 |
| User1 | Act2 | 0 | 2022-07-01 |
| User1 | Act3 | 2 | 2022-07-01 |
| User2 | Act1 | 5 | 2022-07-01 |
| User2 | Act2 | 4 | 2022-07-01 |
| User2 | Act3 | 1 | 2022-07-01 |
| User3 | Act1 | 1 | 2022-07-01 |

I want to find out for 1 activity specifically, what the difference in value is between two dates (today and 5 days ago) for **EACH** user.

I've been trying the following:

```
SELECT
Username,
SUM(
    (SELECT value FROM table1 WHERE activity = 'Act1' AND DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d')=CURRENT_DATE())
    - (SELECT value FROM table1 WHERE activity = 'Act1' AND DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d')=DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 5 day))) as 'difference_5_days'
FROM table1
group by Username
```

This results in a 'subquery return more than one row'. I feel like I need to specify the users in the subquery because now the query doesn't know for which user to calculate the difference. But not sure how to make it variable because I want the results from all users.
So create a list with:
|Username|Difference_5_days|
|:------:|:---------------:|
| User1  | 3               |
| User2  | 0               |
| User3  | 12              |

etc.

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
Username,
SUM(
    (SELECT value FROM table1 sub WHERE sub.username = main.Username and activity = 'Act1' AND DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d')=CURRENT_DATE())
    - (SELECT value FROM table1 sub WHERE sub.username = main.Username and activity = 'Act1' AND DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d')=DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 5 day))) as 'difference_5_days'
FROM table1 main
group by Username
```

You have to give your tables a name and reference on that. If you have questions, let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! I changed it based on your suggestion and it starts running, but nothing happens. I even put a limit of 1 (as the table contains over 1 million records) but still nothing after 2 hours. Any idea?

Comment: What means nothing? Can you make me an example in dbfiddle?